# Truncate on a select

Tags: mysql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT     
 SUM(`SPEND_AMOUNT`) AS 'Total Spend Amount',
 SUM(`SPEND_AMOUNT`)  / COUNT(DISTINCT `INVOICENUMBER`) AS 'Average Spend Amount' 
FROM 
 `TABLE`
```

I would like to truncate(?) the results for "Average Spend Amount" to two decimal places.Thanks for the help.

Comment: Check this http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/mathematical-functions/mysql-truncate-function.php

Answer (score 0):

Round(SUM(`SPEND_AMOUNT`)  / COUNT(DISTINCT `INVOICENUMBER`), 2)